# Java playFramework2: how to put value to form field before post

Tags: java, forms, playframework, persistence

I have entity for reporting. I wonna know who filled up report. I would like to put id of user from session to form class.

I've tried already methods like: bind, fill; but no working solution found.
Ofcorse I mean form class: play.data.Form.form

How can I achive this?
Please help.

Here is my approach (when I wrote this Post):

```
static Form<Registry> modelForm = form(Registry.class);

Registry registry = new Registry();
registry.creationUser = User.getCurrentUser();
registry.test="tt";
modelForm.fill(registry);
modelForm.bind(data, allowedFields)
```

My submit method

```
@Transactional
public static Result submit() {
    modelForm = modelForm.bindFromRequest();
    if (modelForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.Registry.form.render(modelForm));
    } else {
        modelForm.get();
    }
    registry.creationUser = User.getCurrentUser();
    modelForm.fill(registry);

    if (modelForm.hasErrors()) {
        Logger.debug(modelForm.toString());
        return badRequest(views.html.Registry.form.render(modelForm));
    } else {
        modelForm.get().toDataBase();
        toLog("success", "Succefully added new Report");
        flash("success", "Pomyślnie dodano.");
        return redirect(routes.Index.index());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set default value in `Form<YourClass>` by filling it with dummy object, anyway need to show us your approach

Comment: added approach to post

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `Report` model like:

```
public Date date;
public User user;
public String message;
```

You need to create and fill an object first (without saving to DB!) and then fill the form with it, like:

```
Report report = new Report(); // constructors params are welcome here
report.user = loggedUser;
report.date = new Date();

Form<Report> reportForm = Form.form(Report.class).fill(report);

// OR
Form<Report> reportForm = Form.form(Report.class);
reportForm = reportForm().fill(report);

// NOT
Form<Report> reportForm = Form.form(Report.class);
reportForm().fill(report); // Wrong!

return ok(reportCreatingView.render(reportForm));
```

**Edit:** You don't need to fill User data at first step, as actually you can add it after binding, you have too much lines in your `submit()` action, keep it simple :)

```
public static Result submit() {

    User user = User.getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null) return unauthorized("You must log in");

    modelForm = modelForm.bindFromRequest();

    if (modelForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.Registry.form.render(modelForm));
    } 

    // At this point you have a logged User obj which is not null, 
    // you have modelForm without errors (checked previously) 
    // so you need to only add the user to form and save it.

    Registry registry = modelForm.get();    
    registry.creationUser = user;
    registry.save();

    flash("success", "Twój log został zapisany w bazie.");
    return redirect(routes.Index.index());
}
```

Comment: It worked. But after Post it dosnt worked. I've got an error. Should I add this value after post instead of before?

Comment: After update you DON'T need to fill te Form anymore, just bindFromRequest(); Show your update action

Comment: So I will have to have hidden text input for my user?

Comment: yes. and it's name attribute MUST be `user.id` (not `user`), optionally you can add the user AFTER bindingFromRequest, anyway you need to show what you have now there)

Comment: I've posted my submit method. I would go with after bind method adding user. Can You give me some snippets?